# Redirecting Different Case URLs to a Base

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We have a compliance issue with a supplier as if you type the URL with incorrect capitals their brand is wrong.  We are on a private apache server so can edit htaccess etc as needed.

The URL is /example/Brand-Name
We would like all the following variations to resolve back to /example/Brand-Name/ (as 301 redirects)

```
/example/BRAND-NAME/
/example/brand-name/
/example/Brand-name/
/example/brand-Name/
```

etc etc.

All the htaccess things I have tried have lead to infinite loops.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} /example/Brand-Name/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !/example/Brand-Name/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/Brand-Name/$ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you got your rules to work at all, since your `%{HTTP_HOST}` var is never going to look like `/example/Brand-Name/`. You probably want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/Brand-Name/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example/brand-name/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^example/brand-name/(.*)$ /example/Brand-Name/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following two things?  Your NoCase statement as just brand-name (not spelled exactly as your correct version) and, switching the order of the rules.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/example/Brand-Name/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/example/brand-name/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/Brand-Name/$ [R=301,L]
```

I believe the way this works is like an AND statement in an IF.  If Line1 AND Line2, then do rewrite rule. Try these adjustments and let me know.  If that doesn't work I will do a bit of research for you.

Edit: A quick search and I see a lot of rewrites looking like this - !^/ - so perhaps you need to add the little roofy ^ guy after your !. I believe in rewrite this denotes the begging of where to match, and should probably be on the 2nd line as well.